# Simple Bayesian Network causal independence

Tags: artificial-intelligence, bayesian, bayesian-networks

`enter code here`I'm trying to answer this:

A->B

P(A) = 0.5

P(B|A=T) = 0.7

P(B|A=F) = 0.8

Then P(A|B) = ?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question about programming.

Comment: There are several other question related to this, I think artificial intelligence is pretty close to programming :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first of all apply the Bayes rule and you get:

```
P(A|B) = P(A) * P(B|A) / P(B)
```

then you sum over the values of a to get:

```
P(A|B) = P(A) * P(B|A) / (sum_{a} P(B,a))
```

and then you apply the chain rule:

```
P(A|B) = P(A) * P(B|A) / (sum_{a} P(B|a) * P(a))
```

Using this formula you can then easily compute the probability of P(A = a | B = b).

Comment: Thanks, I have one more question: is this true http://pastebin.com/AQgKgDR3 ?